# Accessing a routers configuration page under another router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have a router Asus RT-N12+ (Router mode) DHCP Enabled but Manual Assignment of IP is set. With this Router it has 5 sub routers mode connected via LAN (few connected directly with the Asus T-N12+ and others are via network switch. See below:

[image: router web interface]

But since all these Flat 7, 8, 9, 10, & 11 are in router mode, I cannot acces their configuration page. How can I do that? The only way for me to open their configuration page is by connecting to each respestive network SSID or via lan ports directly to those routers. See Diagram below:

[image: network structure diagram]

I found this page and check if this is for that?

[image: another web interface]

Comment: Can you ping the routers?  Most likely the issue is those routers are not accepting connections on their WAN Interfaces (but there could be other issues).  Look at section 10 of https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/archer-c60_v3/chapter-13-manage-the-router#ug-sub-title-9 for the Archer 60 routers and check if remote management has been enabled under Advanced->System Tools->Administration->Remote Management

Comment: As your routers are adjacent to each other, the Advanced Settings -> LAN page you have found is unlikely to help you, as the router will already know its peers because of the netmask - indeed if it didn't, the clients behind the other routers would not be able to find your main router.

Comment: hi david, thank you for your reply. Actually, all of the sub routers has this remote management. I checked the TP-Link, Asus, and Dlink subrouters and now I can dial their WAN IP addresses and configured it.

I was looking for this solution for years, and thank you for the solution. Our partment has 12 apartments and I have to visit each of these apartments to configure or if someone wants to add their devices in that particular routers because its all in MAC filtering.